# Celery can't decide if it has a result backend or not

Tags: python, redis, celery

When Celery is staring up, it states that it has a backend like this:

```
- ** ---------- .> app:         app.celery:0x7f5fe5f80b80
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379/10
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://redis:6379/11
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
```

But then when I try to run a bit of a complex task, I get this error:

```
NotImplementedError: Starting chords requires a result backend to be configured
```

Celery is configured like this:

```
Celery(__name__, broker="redis://redis:6379/10", backend="redis://redis:6379/11", tasks_acks_late=True)
```

Tasks are functions decorated with `@app.task(base=MyBaseTask, bind=True)`, and the top level task is constructed in a way that there will be chords in there. The top level task is executed as `my_task.delay()`, and this is the line that throws the exception.

I understand why I need result backed to run my task, but I don't understand why it thinks that one isn't configured.

Any idea what I could be missing here?

EDIT: It might be important to note that I have the same codebase deployed on two k8s pods, one as an API server and one as a Celery worker. I'm calling `.delay()` on the API server and expecting the worker to pick up the task and run it. It is call to `.delay()` on the API pod that is throwing the exception. Each of the two pods instantiates its own Celery app, so I'm wondering if that is causing my problem?